# QGIS 2.0.1 - problems to add layers - encoding?

Tags: layers, qgis-2, encoding

I have just installed standalone QGIS 2.0.1 on a PC with Windows 8.
But, when I open it and try to add layers nothing happens?
I browse to find the file I want and click 'open' but it doesn't turn up as a 'dataset' under 'source'. My first thought was that it is something with the encoding (it says 'system'). The encoding on my other PC with QGIS 1.8.0 is set to 'UTF-8'.

I installed QGIS 2.0.1 on another PC with Windows 8 a few months ago, and it works fine. 
What can I have done wrong? Can it be something with the settings?

I have tried with both .shp and .ecw-files.

Comment: It is better to specify the file format/extension for a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried all the source types when have searched for your file or, at least, the `file` source type?

[image]

Or, can you see your file in `Windows Explorer`?

Then, please, try to *drag and drop* your file directly into the QGIS `Layers` panel:

[image]

Remember, also, not to put your files directly in the `c:\` root directory!

Comment: First I tried the file source type, then the others, first with a .shp and later with a .ecw. Didn't work. I also tried to drag-and-drop, but that doesn't work either?

Comment: But are your files visible within Wiindows Explorer?

Comment: Maybe you need to set the folder's visibility like here: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/show-hidden-files-in-windows-8/

Comment: Try to move your files in a path like this: **c:\SpatialFiles** using no spaces and no special characters, then try again.

Comment: I moved my files, and now it worked! I had them on a USB, and then I moved them to C:\. Now I am going to try to set the folder's visibility, to see if that helps even more.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it works!

Comment: @SoS Please accept this answer if it solved your problem